# Nodejs mysql timezone issue

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

I am using the node `mysql` library.

In one of my Insert Queries I used `now()` to insert the current time. However, I am seeing a different time than the one in my time zone. I am using the cleardb from heroku as my mysql database. I did not find any settings there to change the time zone. Is is a bad practice to use `now()`? Is there a javascript alternative that I can use to get the current date and time that is similar to `now()`?

Comment: "I did not find any settings there to change the time zone. Is is a bad practice to use `now()`?" It's a bad practice to store data in your database using anything other than UTC. Don't change your database; change your code so it displays time using whatever time zone you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use new Date(); in Javascript or something similar get the current date/time in UTC and store that UTC format dateTime to the database.

After you query the date (ex: select Date from table1;) and return it to the front end, you can use .toLocaleString(); to convert it to "normal" dateTime string. and you can even further use the .toLocaleString options to display the dateTime in the format that you want, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: `new Date()` was giving me incorrect time zone as well but this worked `(new Date ((new Date((new Date(new Date())).toISOString() )).getTime() - ((new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()*60000))).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');`